# Blocking Websites

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, home-networking, website, blocking

I use Linux, I connect to Internet through Ethernet, I made a Hot-spot, so that I can share my Internet with my Family Members, now I see the that one of my elder was getting addicted to illegal sites, So I want to block those sites. To create Hot-spot, I have used a `Tp-link TL-WN722N` Usb-wifi Network adapter.(External)

That elder uses Android, he doesn't known much about Internet and stuff, but I want to be on safe side,rather than asking him his mobile and setting up 'filter search results' in browser. So I want to block websites, from my side such that he can't access any stupid stuff.

so basically everyone gets Internet through my Laptop.

My ISP doesn't Block any Web-sites.

Tp-link TL-WN722N Details:

```
      IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

I need solution for this answer for Linux Operating System.

Thank You in Advance..

Comment: What firewall do you have installed on that server?

Comment: It isn't a server, just a home hot-spot, I doesn't have any firewall, just basic security by Linux distro

Comment: You could also consider how your elder found these websites. In order to save him from finding new ones in future, perhaps you should install an AdBlocking browser on his phone, such as [Brave](https://brave.com/) or [Opera](https://opera.com) with the AdBlock extension.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you only call it a `home hot-spot`, it is actually being used as a router for your elderly and you want that router to include security, which is what a firewall is for.

Simply install a firewall and apply the rules to reject the addresses you want to block.  It's as simple as that.

Note that however simple it may be to block specific addresses, finding which addresses to block can be a completely different story.

Answer (score 0):

In linux its iptables
install ipset and iptables if not already installed.

```
ipset create banned_hosts hash:net family inet hashsize 65536 maxelem 200000 counters comment

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set -j DROP  --match-set banned_nets src
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m set -j DROP  --match-set banned_nets src
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -m set -j DROP  --match-set banned_nets dst
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m set -j DROP  --match-set banned_nets dst
```

You will have to save and restore the list before/after rebooting.

```
ipset save >/somewhere/ban.txt
ipset restore </somewhere/ban.txt
```

If your linux uses systemd, I have a couple rules to automate it.
The file should look something like this, but the before and after list could be different.

create
/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/ipset.service

```
[Unit]
Description=IP sets for iptables
After=ufw.service
Before=network.target
Before=iptables.service
Before=webmin-iptables.service
AssertPathExists=/src/all.txt

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/sbin/ipset restore -f /src/all.txt
ExecStop=/sbin/ipset save -f /src/all.txt
#ExecReload=/usr/libexec/ipset/ipset.start-stop reload
# Save current ipset entries on stop/restart.
#   Value: yes|no,  default: no
# Saves all ipsets to /etc/sysconfig/ipset if ipset gets stopped
Environment=IPSET_SAVE_ON_STOP=yes IPSET_SAVE_ON_RESTART=no

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```